# Using an ArrayList of custom class and setting variables at different times

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am just getting into Java and programming in general.

I have class Dogs:

```
public class Dog {
    String name;
    String URL;

    public Dog(){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }
}
```

I want to have a total of 300 or so Dogs. For this purpose I only included the "names" and "URL" variables, although in reality, I will have about 10 more variables for each object. I thought the best way to work with them would be to make an `ArrayList<Dog>`. So the first thing that I set is the URLs, which I do here:

```
static ArrayList<Dog> dogInfo = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element e : dogURLs) {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    dog.setURL(e.attr("src").toString());
    dogInfo.add(dog);
}
```

This works fine and as expected. I am able to get each individual URL by

```
for (int i = 0; i<dogInfo.size(); i++){
     Log.i("DogURL", dogInfo.get(i).getURL());
}
```

But when I try to add the name next is where I'm having problem. My thought process is that the objects have already been added to the ArrayList, so I just need to use the name setter instead of adding a new element to the ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogInfo.size(); i++) {
    dogInfo.get(i).setName(dogNamesElement.text());
}
```

But when doing this, and printing to the logs, it appears as if every element in the ArrayList contains the entire list of names.

```
for (int i = 0; i<dogInfo.size(); i++){
     Log.i("DogNames", dogInfo.get(i).getName());
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, is this the best way to handle working with data like this? I'm pretty new so if the way I'm doing this is non-optimal then please let me know before I go any further.

Comment: What is **dogNamesElement** ..?

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to put too much unnecessary code to just show relevant information. **dogNamesElement** and **dogURLs** are both elements from an HTML page parsed from the jsoup library. I have confirmed that they both output the correct string, but the issue is it seems as if the setName() for loop I am using gives each index in the ArrayList the whole list of names, as opposed to 1 per index.

Comment: I think what you need is to iterate over a collection of dogNamesElement objects, keep a counter variable, and update a single Dog instance at the index your counter represents, increment it, then move onto the next dogNamesElement. Repeat till you're out of dogNameElements or Dog objects in your collection.... but its hard to say given that I don't know what's in dogNamesElement. Could be that you have many of them with a singular dog name in it, or it could be that it has all of them in some delimited text.

Comment: Please move your solution as an answer instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I changed it from an enhanced for loop to a regular for loop and forgot to use get(index) on the dogNameElement.

dogInfo.get(i).setName(dogNamesElement.get(i).text());

instead of

dogInfo.get(i).setName(dogNamesElement.text());